# c concatenate variable length int to a string without printing it

Tags: c, string, int, concatenation

I need to concatenate an integer to a system call string:

`status = system("./run test.txt " + integer);`

`integer` here can be any int.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: By "without printing it" do you mean the `sprintf()` / `snprintf()` functions may not be used?  If so, why?

Comment: Nope, sorry, just very new to C, by the naming of those functions I somewhy thought they would be printing the output to screen.

Comment: `sprintf` prints to a "string" (`char *`, really). `printf` prints to `stdout` by default and `fprintf` prints to a `FILE *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) (or [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) if you don't have `snprintf` or need your code to run on systems without it) to print to a char buffer, and pass that to the `system` call.

e.g.

```
#define MAX_LEN 128
char buffer[MAX_LEN];
int val = 0;
snprintf(buffer, MAX_LEN, "./run test.txt %d", val);

// you would be wise to check that snprintf has not truncated your command
// before passing it to system()
status = system(buffer);
```

Alternatively, you could calculate how many characters the integer needs and then allocate an exactly correctly sized buffer. This would allow you to use `sprintf` safely and removes the need to check for truncation - [chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26497268/696485) demonstrates this. Note that this may not be a good strategy if you cannot use VLAs (C89) and have reasons to avoid `malloc()`, e.g. on some embedded systems.

Comment: @R Sahu Using `snprintf` is only marginally safer in that it did not overflow `buffer`.  This codes use of `snprintf()` can cause another problem: execution of a truncated command.  It would be far better to _detect_ that the buffer may overflow and not execute a _system_ command rather than go ahead with a truncated one.

Comment: This was not intended as a complete example on how to call system() safely when using constructing a command string, merely an example of how to (safely) concatenate a string and an integer into a buffer and pass the buffer a function, but I have added a comment about the former anyway.

Comment: Also given OP's situation he should be able to calculate the max length of the command a priori anyway.

Comment: Iskar Jarak If the command length is check a priori, the need for `snprintf()` (vs. `sprintf()`) can be negated.  Your answer did not tout `snprintf()` being better than `sprintf()`, it is that @R Sahu promoted `snprintf()`, but missed the truncation problem. To solve _that_ problem, `snprintf()` does not buy much over `printf()`.  Like `int` overflow, best to detect overflow before-hand.

Comment: @chux My point was merely that I believe the question to be about concatenation, so teaching OP about `snprintf` is relevant.

Comment: @Iskar Jarak Maybe add code to show how to use `snprintf()` to detect an incomplete concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

After accept answer

Use a right-sized buffer via [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) or `malloc()`.  Estimating a fixed buffer size may overflow the buffer with `sprintf()` or create a truncated result with `snprintf()`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int system_command_int(const char *command, int i) {
  #define INT_PRINT_SIZE(i) ((sizeof(i) * CHAR_BIT)/3 + 3)
  char buf[strlen(command) + 1 + INT_PRINT_SIZE(i) + 1];

  sprintf(buf, "%s %d",command, i);
  return system(buf);
}

int status = system_command_int("./run test.txt", integer);
```

---

The `INT_PRINT_SIZE(i)` macro returns the `char` size needed to accommodate decimal representation of integer type `i`.  With some integer types, the result may be 1 or 2 extra, but is never too small.  Alternatively, code could use `10*sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT/33 + 3` which has less *extra* overhead.  The idea is to multiple the bit width by some integer a/b fraction that is near and >= log10(2) or ~0.30103.  This size does include the `char` need for the trailing `'\0'`.  So the above `char buf[]` does not need the trailing `+ 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf):

```
char buffer[256];
sprintf(buffer,"./run test.txt %d",integer);
status = system(buffer);
```

Comment: Does the length of the buffer matter here? Why did you use 256?

Comment: Buffer length just needs to be long enough. If you have snprintf and don't need to worry about portability use that instead.

Comment: @YemSalat: It needs to be long enough for your command and the longest int that might fit.

Comment: The buffer needs to be sufficient, 256 is just some arbitrary "big enough" value.  In this case one could argue that an int will take up at max 11 characters (assuming 32 bits ints), so the length of the fixed portion of the string (15) + 11 + 1 to accommodate the terminating \0 = 27 should be enough.  The safer snprintf function that limits the length of its output, as suggested by @IskarJarak makes that math obsolete.

Comment: @fvu Using `snprintf()` to simple limit the characters printed to the buffer is insufficient.  Calling a _system_ function with a truncated buffer is a major problem.  Additional code is needed when using `snprintf()` or `sprint()` to prevent using too small a buffer.

Answer (score 2):

see man sprintf

```
char buf[150];

sprintf(buf, "./run test.txt %d", integer);
status = system(buf);
```

Make sure buf isn't too small.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define COMMAND_SIZE 100

char command[COMMAND_SIZE];
sprintf(command, "./run test.txt %d", integer);
status = system(command);
```

Comment: Why is COMMAND_SIZE=100 here ?

Comment: @YemSalat, it's one way of capturing the maximum length of `command`.