# How to determine the size of the char array really need?

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have a question about the following code:

```
void testing(int idNumber)
{
    char name[20];

    snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "number_%d", idNumber);
}
```

The size of the char array `name` is 20, so if the `idNumber` is `111` it works, but how about the actual idNumber is `111111111111111111111111111111`, how to determine how big the char array should be in order to keep the result of `snprintf`?

Comment: It's easy enough to calculate the size required for any numeric type: `2^(sizeof(type) * 8)` is the maximum (unsigned) value of the type. a one byte type (`char` or `short`) allows for a 3 digit number, 2 bytes 5 (the minimal size of an `int`), 8, 10, 13, and so on (so the interval is 2 or 3 chars). Add the sign char and room for a terminating `\0` char, and `sizeof(type) * 3 + 2` should do the trick. If you are processing `double`s and `float`s, add room for a decimal point, too

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem Note: processing `double` with `"%f"` _could_ need a buffer of size `1 + DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 1 + 1 + 6 +1` for the sign, DBL_MAX digits, ., fraction and `'\0'`.  At least 47 and maybe 318 `char` as on my platform.  Your suggested formula works well for integers.

Comment: @chux: indeed... I'd like to see the length required on a system where the `long double` is implemented as a quadrupal precision type (128 bit)

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem `long double` uses one [B.A.Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._A._Baracus). ;-)  (Maybe 4942 `char`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one good answer:
Ask `snprintf` itself (Pass a length of 0).

It returns the size of the output it would have written if the buffer was big enough, excluding the terminating 0.

[man-page for `snprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Standard-quote (C99+Amendments):

> #### 7.21.6.5 The snprintf function
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n,
> const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> Description
>   2 The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into
>   an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream. If `n` is zero, nothing is written,
>   and `s` may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`st are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end
>   of the characters actually written into the array. If copying takes place between objects
>   that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>   Returns
>   3 The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
>   value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been
>   completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`.

Comment: Something like `char name[snprintf(name, 0, "number_%d", idNumber) + 1]; snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "number_%d", idNumber);`?

Comment: or even `snprintf(NULL, 0, "format", extra, arguments)`

Answer (score 3):

Well, if `int` is 32 bits on your platform, then the widest value it could print would be -2 billion, which is 11 characters, so you'd need 7 for `number_`, 11 for `%d`, and 1 for the null terminator, so 19 total.

But you should check the return value from `snprintf()` generally, to make sure you had enough space.  For example, if the "locale" is set to other than the standard "C" one, it could print thousands separators, in which case you'd need 2 more characters than you have.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation of snprintf. If you pass NULL for the destination and 0 for the size, it will return the number of bytes needed. So you do that first, malloc the memory, and do another snprintf with the right size.

All the printf functions return the number of bytes printed (excluding a trailing zero), except snprintf will return the number of characters that *would* have been printed if the length was unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

> If the resulting string would be longer than n-1 characters, the
>   remaining characters are discarded and not stored, but counted for the
>   value returned by the function.

Answer (score 1):

To use a right-sized buffer, calculate its maximum needs.

```
#define INT_PRINT_SIZE(i) ((sizeof(i) * CHAR_BIT)/3 + 3)

void testing(int idNumber) {
  const char format[] = "number_%d";
  char name[sizeof format + INT_PRINT_SIZE(idNumber)];
  snprintf(name, sizeof(name), format, idNumber);
}
```

This approach assumes C locale.  A more robust solution could use

```
  ...
  int cnt = snprintf(name, sizeof(name), format, idNumber);
  if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sizeof(name)) Handle_EncodingError_SurprisingLocale().
```

Akin to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26497268/2410359